# What happens if both forward and reverse primers have same Tm?

Tags: pcr, primer

One of the key rules in primer designing is that `Tm` (melting temperature) of forward and reverse primers should be in the range of ±5°C. For example, if `Tm` of forward primer is 62°C, then reverse primer should be either 67°C or 57°C.

What happens if both the primers are having same `Tm`?

Is this to be considered as perfect score of finding correct primers set?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually good if both the primers have the same `Tm` (Melting Temperature) because you would basically want both primers to anneal at your `Ta` (Annealing Temperature) which is generally set as `Tm-5`. If the `Tm(s)` don't match, then your `Ta` should be set according to the lower `Tm`.